# Blender API: Setting the current vertex-color brush color

Tags: python

I’m trying to use the API to add two buttons/hotkeys to Blender that will quickly darken and lighten the current color that Vertex Color mode uses when doing Set Vertex Color (Shift+K).

Basically, get the current color, alter it, set the current color.

I can’t figure out how to get/set this color though.

I tried the API call below, but it doesn’t set the color that Shift+K will use next:

```
bpy.context.tool_settings.vertex_paint.brush.color = Color((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Explain your problem in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that brush.secondary_color not shown in header in Blender < 3.2

get colors:

```
# get brush.color
brush_color_first = bpy.context.tool_settings.vertex_paint.brush.color
print("primary color:", brush_color_first)

# get brush.secondary_color
brush_color_second = bpy.context.tool_settings.vertex_paint.brush.secondary_color
print("secondary color:", brush_color_second)
```

change colors: float array of 3 items in [0, 1], default (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

```
# change brush.color  
bpy.context.tool_settings.vertex_paint.brush.color = (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) 

# change brush.secondary_color  
bpy.context.tool_settings.vertex_paint.brush.secondary_color = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

set colors: Fill the active vertex color layer with the current paint color (primary/secondary)

```
bpy.ops.paint.vertex_color_set()
```

Comment: Ah, I was declaring my new colors incorrectly. Thank you!